# approval workflow

Tags: .net, sharepoint, workflow

I am trying to create a document approval work flow without sending any email.how could i know that the document is approved .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, pretty vague, but I'll give it a shot...  If you use the MOSS Approval Workflow or simply content approval (available in WSS and MOSS), there will be an extra column in the list/library for the approval.  You can simply make sure you have a view that includes this column to see the value.  If you want to be alerted when this changes, you can create a view that filters to those that are complete and add an alert for items that meet this view.

Answer (score 1):

Too vague. Please supply more information. Sounds like a BPM of some sort, but I'm not sure where exactly you're going with it.